# Were Sarah, Phil and Vic's deaths coincidental, or where they specifically targeted because of their proximity to the main characters?

Tags: plot-explanation, glitch

In the science fiction series *Glitch*, the characters Sarah, Phil and Vic all die in quick succession in ways that are apparently unrelated to each other, and unrelated to the main story arch (haemorrhaging after child birth, industrial accident, motor vehicle accident).

However, all three characters have close relationships with people involved in the main story, allowing them to be used as hosts to get close to them.

Were their deaths complete coincidences, and they just happened to be friends or relatives of the main cast, or were they specifically targeted and killed so that they could be used as hosts?

Comment: After watching the last season, the answer is probably that they were targeted. As some of those taken over specifically refence this phenomena.